# Using CASE with Table Join

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am using Oracle 11g.

I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

I want to display student_name, course, fee and a column with discounted fee where the fee is reduced by 10% if it is either 'BIT' or 'MIT'.

I've come up with following query but it gives an error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected:

```
SQL> SELECT Student.student_name, Specification.course, Specification.specification_name, Specification.fee
  2  FROM Student
  3  JOIN Specification ON Student.specification_id = Specification.specification_id
  4     CASE Specification.course WHEN 'BIT' THEN 0.9 * Specification.fee
  5                               WHEN 'MIT' THEN 0.9 * Specification.fee
  6     ELSE Specification.fee END "DISCOUNTED FEE";
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but for most SQL you would add you case expression *before* your *from*.

Comment: I tried that too, but still gives the same error

Comment: I doubt that, please show us

Comment: Also I highly recommend the use of table aliases for readability.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Execute `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION`, then **edit your question** and include this information, along with the specifications of your tables (all field names, data types, and keys (primary and foreign)). That might let us understand why a simple CASE expression is causing such difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `decode` as follows:

```
SELECT Student.student_name, 
       Specification.course, 
       Specification.specification_name, 
       decode(Specification.course, 'BIT', 0.9, 'MIT', 0.9, 1)
         * Specification.fee AS "DISCOUNTED FEE"
  FROM Student
  JOIN Specification ON Student.specification_id = Specification.specification_id;
```

Comment: thanks, this did what I was intending to do.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you seem like need to use `CASE WHEN` in `SELECT` instead of `FROM`

```
SELECT Student.student_name, Specification.course, Specification.specification_name, Specification.fee,
       (CASE WHEN  Specification.cours = 'BIT' THEN 0.9 * Specification.fee
             WHEN  Specification.cours = 'MIT' THEN 0.9 * Specification.fee
        ELSE Specification.fee END) "DISCOUNTED FEE"
FROM Student
JOIN 
    Specification ON Student.specification_id = Specification.specification_id;
```

I would like to use `CASE WHEN` with `IN` let the SQL be cleaner.

```
SELECT Student.student_name, Specification.course, Specification.specification_name, Specification.fee,
       (CASE WHEN Specification.cours IN ('BIT','MIT') THEN 0.9 * Specification.fee
        ELSE Specification.fee END) "DISCOUNTED FEE"
FROM Student
JOIN 
    Specification ON Student.specification_id = Specification.specification_id;
```

Comment: this gives an error ORA-00905: missing keyword in CASE statement. Got the gist thanks

Comment: @SamitPaudel Is my edit answer work for you?